# CEF sharp set authproxy at runtime

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying use cefsharp set authproxy at runtime. This is my current code. I use this code but it not work， alaways show my local ip . my cef version 75.1.142.0,I implement IRequestHandler this interface，But I find GetAuthCredentials never be used.

```
                public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
                string URL = "https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent";
                public MainWindow()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();         
                       InitWebBrowser();
                }
                private void InitWebBrowser()
                {
                    CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
                    try
                    {
                        Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext();
                    this.chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.ipip.net");
                    this.browserContainer.Content = this.chromeBrowser;
                    this.chromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += this.chromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
                }
                private  void chromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                      this.proxy();

                }
                public async void proxy()
                {
                    await this.SetProxy(this.chromeBrowser, "ip:port");
                }
                private async Task SetProxy(ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser, string Address)
                {
                    await Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate()
                    {
                            chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler("username", "pw");
                            IRequestContext requestContext =chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
                            string messageBoxText;
                            bool flag = requestContext.SetPreference("proxy", new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                {
                                    "mode",
                                    "fixed_servers"
                                },
                                {
                                    "server",
                                     Address
                                }
                            }, out messageBoxText);


                    });
              }
```

I implemented IRequestHandler this interface

```
public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
            {
                bool result;
                if (isProxy)
                {
                    callback.Continue(this.username, this.password);
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    callback.Dispose();
                    result = false;
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: What is the value of messageboxtext? Your not checking to see if SetPreference was actually successfully. Also check the logfile see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: thank you！ I will check it now